# get count of reference id and it is their child recursively

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have the below table( I need them for oracle and sql server):

```
id  id_reference
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1

6    2
7    2
8    3
9    8
10   0
11   10
12   10
13   12
```

I want to get the count of the id_reference for each id.

the result

```
id   count(1)
1   7 -- because id 1 2 3 4 and the child 6 7 8 9 are referring to the id
2   2 -- because id 6 and 7 are referring to it
3   2 -- because id 8 and the child 9 referring to it
4   0 -- non are referring to them
6   0 -- non are referring to them   
7   0 -- non are referring to them   
8   1 -- because 9 is referring to the id
10  3 -- because 11 , 12 and 13 are referring
11  0 -- none are referring
12  1 -- 13 is referring to id
13  0 -- none is referring to id
```

this what I tried but I need it to be recursive.

```
select count(1),
                 id,
                 (select count(1) from tab e2 where e2.id <=e1.id and id_ref in ( select id from tab e3 where e3.id_ref= e2.id )
            from tab e1
           group by id 
           order by id desc
```

Comment: You want a [CTE (common table expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) supported by both SQL Server and Oracle (but minor syntactic differences).

Comment: Are using SQL Server or Oracle? The syntax between both is not identical.

Comment: @Richard I am trying to learn how to use CTE expression recurevly

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos the query i write it first on oracle I though it would function on sql server. ill check now

Comment: There are literally thousands and thousands of examples of recursive ctes all over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle version:

<sup>**[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c275b5172e755d72cee1425b8564965)**</sup>

```
select distinct id, nvl(cnt, 0)
  from tab 
  left join (
    select root, count(1) cnt
      from (
        select tab.*, connect_by_root(id) root
          from tab 
          where level > 1
          connect by id_reference = prior id)
      group by root) r on root = tab.id
  order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server (2016+), this is how I'd achieve the above result set:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1 ,0 ),
                 (2 ,1 ),
                 (3 ,1 ),
                 (4 ,1 ),
                 (6 ,2 ),
                 (7 ,2 ),
                 (8 ,3 ),
                 (9 ,8 ),
                 (10,0 ),
                 (11,10),
                 (12,10),
                 (13,12)) V(ID, ID_ref)),
CTE AS (
    SELECT ID,
           CONVERT(varchar(30),CONVERT(varchar(4),ID)) AS Delimited
    FROM VTE V
    WHERE V.ID_ref = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT V.ID,
           CONVERT(varchar(30),CONCAT(C.Delimited,',' + CONVERT(varchar(4),V.ID)))
    FROM CTE C
         JOIN VTE V ON V.ID_ref = C.ID),
Splits AS(
    SELECT C.ID,
           SS.value
    FROM CTE C
         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(C.Delimited,',') SS)
SELECT V.ID,
       COUNT(S.ID) - 1 AS [Count]
FROM VTE V
     JOIN Splits S ON S.[value] = V.ID
GROUP BY V.ID;
```

This firstly creates a delimited list of each ID at each layer. It then splits them out and finally does a Count -1.

If you aren't on SQL Server 2016+, then you can use a XML Splitter or `delimitedsplit8k(_lead)`.

*Note that a rCTe will stop recursing at 100 loops. You'll need to use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION N)` to increase the loops (where `N` is a suitable number of the maximum layer you might have).*

Comment: Hearing the reason for the downvote would be nice; how can this be further improved?